# saving track of changes made by users in a Multi-user sql database

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, database-design

I'm working on a design of a relational database. It has several tables and there are multiple users on application level. I need to know that changes to a certain record of a certain table are made, by which user, which time, and what has actually changed. There is a table for saving the user's information and this table is also included in this behavior.

How should I do this in the SQL database design so I can let users see which one of them made these changes?

Comment: Sounds like you want a trigger on that table to write away some audit information when that table is changed.

Comment: i thought of something myself but i don't know how much effective is that.

Comment: my solution is : that I add 3 fields to the same table one is gonna have the PK of the user that made that change , 2nd is date/time of change and 3rd is the pk of the record that has been changed. these fields would be added to the same table. it means everytime a user gonna make a change to the data of one/more fields of a record in that table instead of update command we gonna insert a new record what do u think?

Comment: That allows you to always know who and when the latest changes was made - but only that very latest change. Also: it doesn't provide any way to know what the row looked like *before* this latest change. If that's enough information for you - go ahead!

Comment: Often, you'd want to write that information (*who* changed *which* row and *when*) to a separate audit table. This would allow you to see a history of changes (not just the last one), and it would allow you to see which rows gets modified multiple times over a given period of time. Some systems will also store the values the row had before every change, so that every state of that row could in theory be restored, if needed.

Comment: If you pack the data in the same table then how are you going to query for the latest?  One table would make for some messy TSQL.

Comment: I have to I need to know who changed which row and when and most importantly I wanna know what changed

Comment: also I think u got it wrong about my solution. what I meant was that EVERY TIME a change made to one of fields of a records. we don't UPDATE that record instead we INSERT a new record.

Comment: about the querying the latest I think we could use the TOP keyword on the PK field and use the filter for the records with record_set_id are equal to original PK. but I agree it is kinda messy

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Wiki-like versioning. Basically, for every table you want to keep versions, you'll want to create at least a copy of that table with the fields you mentioned added (userid, when it was added). That's probably all there is to it, as long as you only need to track *changes*. Then, upon an edit, you just create a backup of the current row in that copied table and put the new one in the actual table. This way you can (hopefully) add the versioning without having to touch existing presentational code.

It gets a little more tricky, if you need to record additional actions like creation of new rows and deletion.

If you need a code example, just have look under the hood of some Wiki like https://mediawiki.org/

Comment: You download, install it and look at the source files and the created database schema?

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can look at sql server version tracking mechanisms (row versioning or row changes). After that you can look at sql server audit features. I think sql server audit would be the best for your needs.

On the other hand, if you want to make ad-hok versioning then YOU MUST NOT go to triggers. Imagine, you must create triggers for all tables for inserts, updates and deletes. This IS bad practice.

I think ad-hoc versioning should be avoided (degradation in performance and difficult to support) but in case it cannot be avoided, I would surely use CONTEXT_INFO in order to track current user and then I would try to create something that would read the schema of the table, I would get changes by using sql server change tracking mechanisms and store that in a tablename, changeduser, changedtime, column, prevValue, newValue style. I would not replicate each and every table for the changes.

Comment: imagine a user update data of several of different fields of same records. how do I keep these changes if I'm not gonna replicate the whole table?

Comment: For example if 2 columns changed from the same user, at the same time, I would add in the 'changes' table 2 rows, 1 row with data from the first column and 1 more from the second column... They both should have a same uniqiue id (in order to be able to tie all changes together). But in any case, why don't you use sql server change tracking? All these issues we are talking about are already solved there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx

Comment: its good but unfortunately I can't use it. because I have lets 50 to 100 different users using this app. they are different users on app level but of SQL database level they all are just one user. so from what I read I can't use it for this program

Comment: Well, this is not such a big problem as, if you can manage to set to the CONTEXT_INFO at the dal layer the executing user, then it will be easy to get this information from whichever stored proc or function you are at SQL level and log the changes accordingly. I think change tacking is already handling this, if you manage to set it before execution.